# SQL Pivot after Cross Apply

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, cross-apply

I am trying to do a pivot in SQL Server wherein I need to pivot the following table:

```
key       value
column1    billy
column2    billy@billy.com
column5    NULL
column6    false
column9    true
```

I want the values in the "key" column to be the column headers. Another problem here is that I am using a CROSS APPLY to generate this table from another table. I start with:

```
select * from jtable cross apply openjson(json)
```

which results in the table format shown above.

If I don't use the cross apply, I get a table that looks like this:

```
ID json
1  "column1":billy, "column2":billy@billy.com
2  "column1":steve, "column2":steve@etc.com
```

So I'm trying to end up with a table that looks like this:

```
column1    column2            column3
billy      billy@billy.com    false
steve      steve@etc.com      false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY(SELECT 1)) AS ID
          ,* 
    from jtable 
    cross apply openjson(json)
) DS
PIVOT
(
    MAX([value]) FOR [key] IN ([column1], [column2], [column3], ... , [columnN] )
) PVT
```

If you do not know the number of the columns, search for `dynamic PIVOT`. If you need to sort by other criteria (generate the `ID` in other special way) - you can change the `ROW_NUMBER` function.